# What global (or very large area regional) digital elevation models (DEMs) products are publicly available?

Tags: dem, data, global

What global or large regional area DEM and/or DSM products are publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

> This question has been wiki locked
> because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers.
> It should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
> type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
> site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
> to do so by editing this answer.

---

## BedMachine Antarctica

- Resolution: 500 m
- URL: https://nsidc.org/data/NSIDC-0756/versions/1
- Comments: Antarctica only, but provides bed DEM, not just surface

## BedMachine V3 (Greenland)

- Resolution: 150 m
- URL: https://nsidc.org/data/idbmg4
- Comments: Greenland only, but provides bed DEM, not just surface.

## ETOPO1

- URL: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/
- Resolution: 1 arc-minute (1800 m @ equator) global
- Comment: Global land + bathymetry

## GEBCO_2020

- Resolution: 15 arc-second (~500 m @ equator)
- URL: https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/
- Comments

  - Global, ocean + land
  - Comes with source metadata

## GTOPO 30

- URL: https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-digital-elevation-global-30-arc-second-elevation-gtopo30
- Resolution: 30 arc-second (~1 km @ equator)
- Comment: Global but only land

## NASADEM

- Resolution: 1 arc-second (~30 m @ equator)
- URL: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/news/release-nasadem-data-products/
- Comments: Global, only land, should supersede STRM, STRM15+.

## SRTM15+

- URL: https://topex.ucsd.edu/WWW_html/srtm15_plus.html
- Resolution: 15 arc-second (~500 m @ equator)
- Comments: Global but land only

## TanDEM-X

- Resolution: 90 m
- URL: https://geoservice.dlr.de/data-assets/ju28hc7pui09.html
- Comments

  - Coverage: Land-only -90 S to 84 N.